# How to implement multi-processing into a python module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-module, concurrent.futures

I would like to implement multiprocessing into a simulation which I have written in python. The simulation is very extensive and to clean the code I have created a number of modules.

One of the modules is now supposed to do some number crunching. Thus, I'd like to implement multiprocessing. However, I will always encounter an issue as I can not employ an *if __name__ == "__main__" guard* with in the module.

I can reproduce the error by running the following:

```
# filename: test_mp_module.py

import concurrent.futures

def test_fct(arg):
    return arg

class TestMpModule():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def do(arg):
        para = [1,2,3]
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
            results = executor.map(test_fct, para)
            
            for result in results:
                print(result)
```

and

```
# filename: main.py

from test_mp_module import TestMpModule
                
test = TestMpModule()
test.do()
```

The Exception displayed states:

```
runfile('C:/XXX/test_mp.py', wdir='C:/XXX')
Reloaded modules: test_mp_module
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\XXX\test_mp.py", line 17, in <module>
    test.do()

  File "C:\XXX\test_mp_module.py", line 22, in do
    for result in results:

  File "C:\YYY\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 484, in _chain_from_iterable_of_lists
    for element in iterable:

  File "C:\YYY\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 611, in result_iterator
    yield fs.pop().result()

  File "C:\YYY\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 439, in result
    return self.__get_result()

  File "C:\YYY\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 388, in __get_result
    raise self._exception

BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
```

I'm using Python 3.8.3, usually execute my code in Spyder and run a Windows machine.

How may I adapt my code to utilise multiprocessing within a module? Would that be even possible in the first place - I found very conflicting statements?

Any help is appreciated, cheers.

Comment: Parallel processing really depends on your code, what it does and how it does it. Can your code run asynchronously? have you tried the python-multiprocessing module?

Comment: Yes it can. Basically solving the same minimisation problem. Within this minisation problem an integral needs to be solved. This needs to be done N-times with different parameters chosen each time.

Will try the multiprocessing module next.

Comment: I'd say try Corey Schafer videos, pretty good and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your file "main.py":

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     test = TestMpModule()
     test.do()
```

For the multiprocessing part, I recommend to use the multiprocessing package. Here is a little exemple on how to use it:

```
import multiprocessing


def my_func(i):
    return i


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as p:
        outputs = p.starmap(my_func, [(i, ) for i in range(5)])

    print(outputs)  # > [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Regretfully, this change results in the same BrokenProcessPool Error

Comment: I did try the second example code as well. The code runs endlessly. I will read up on the multiprocessing module and provide feedback if it was helpful Ö=

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution not sure if it is considered pretty, though. The name_guard needs to be carried into the module as follows:

```
# filename: test_mp_module.py

import concurrent.futures

def test_fct(i):
    return i
    
class TestMpModule():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
                
    def do(self, name_guard):
        para = [1, 2, 3]
        if name_guard == 'parent_module_name': # check parent module name here
            with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
                results = executor.map(test_fct, para)
                
                for result in results:
                    print(result)
```

and

```
from test_mp_module import TestMpModule
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    name_guard = "parent_module_name" # insert __name__ here
    test = TestMpModule()
    test.do(name_guard)
```

Works fine now.